# Sending message to user using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have over 100 tests to do .
For every test i need to show the title of testcase, 
I cannot use MessageBox because it stops the tests, i need just to show a popup that contains the title and after 2 sec disappears.

I am using **Selenium** test drive for a web application and **c#**

Comment: Why do you want to show the title of test case while running selenium tests?

Comment: Why isn't something running your tests on a "headless" test environment automatically after a successful deployment?

Comment: every test,takes 20 sec, and my boss and my team needs to know wich test is running on every page

Comment: I think you and your boss would be better off implementing tests that can run unattended, and make sure you've got comprehensive logging and screenshotting in case of test failures.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging . This will give clear picture about this.

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/logging-with-testng-using-listeners

Answer (score 0):

What about injecting html via javascript to your page at the beginning of every test?
I dont know the C# syntax, here's an idea how it may look in java:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode( \"" + testName + "\") );" );
```

Depending on if you reuse your browser across tests, you might need an element something you can clean up after the test.

Or, just change the page title

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "document.title =  \"" + testName + "\";" );
```

Just make sure you choose a way that doesn't interfere with the tests themselves.

But, what I'd really like to suggest is to look into ways of getting more confidence in your automation. If there are reasons for you to manually need to look at what your automation is doing.. that just doesn't sound optimal..

Answer (score 0):

Workaround at best without changing page DOM. How about writing to a html file with the test case name when each test starts in the title tag. Setup a refresh meta-tag with a time of 1-2 secs. Open up the html as a separate window and it keeps on refreshing on its own.